# Posting Json data to console

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to post Json data to my Console. I have the code that is requesting it. I think I either have my Parameters or something else that is wrong. I know I get to the site, but then I get a 500 Server Error. I'm stuck and any help would be appreciated. I took out the URL and USER and Pass. I left the other stuff. I have no idea what I'm doing as I usually work with SQL, but I was told to try this and see if I can get it to work. We are using a Console app with the .NET framework to try and get this to work. Please help as I'm out of ideas. Something might be wrong with the headers.Accept code as well.

I've tried changing the code where my params are, I've tried even google and looking at other stack over flow methods.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      try
        {
            string webAddr ="MYURL";

        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webAddr);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Accept = "application/Json";

        using (var streamWriter = new 
        StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
                {
                    USER_ID = "MyUser",
                    PASSWORD = "MyPass",
                    Query_ID = "4444",
                    Parameters = ""Key" ("Original"),"Value" ("1.1323")

            });

                streamWriter.Write(json);
            }
 var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
 using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine("Here is your Json Data.....");
                Console.WriteLine(responseText);
                Console.ReadLine();

                //Response success above and error below
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

For the Json data to show up in the Console.

Comment: "I call some service with some parameters and get some result I don't like" is not really enough information to provide any answers. Please read [MCVE] guidance on expected quality of code. Based on the code provided it does not look like you have problem with "Posting Json data to console"  despite what title of the post says.

Comment: Wow, you even tried Google! A 500 http status code usually is an "internal server error". So something goes wrong on the server. This could mean they have an outrage or something, but maybe in this case the server doesn't understand your request (I would expect "bad request" or something  response in that case). Anyway, it's impossible to know for us without the api specs.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov It's not posting whenever I run it. But, I think it's because it's expecting something else.

Comment: @DavidLibido Not really much information on this outside of google, and stackoverflow and changing the code. I could ask others on a forum website...HEY! Wait a minute!